# How can I apply my camera to all graphics objects?

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, shaders, camera

Is there a way to have the camera be applied to all objects?

Can you have the camera effect objects that where made with `glVertex3f();`

This is the fourth time I have been writing this post. It keeps deleting. The first time it deleted almost all the text was when I logged in. Anyway ---

This is some of the code that does the camera:

```
    Projection = glm::perspective(fov, display.Ratio(), 0.001f, 1000.0f);
    glm::vec3 Pos = glm::vec3(this->position.x, this->position.y, this->position.z);
    glm::vec3 Target = glm::vec3(this->target.x, this->target.y, this->target.z);
    glm::vec3 Up = glm::vec3(this->up.x, this->up.y, this->up.z);
    glm::mat4 Lookat = glm::lookAt(Pos, Target, Up);
    glm::mat4 ModelV = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 0.0f, Up);
    CamLook = this->Projection * Lookat * ModelV;
```

CamLook is passed to the shader as MVP

Shader Code:

```
#version 400

in vec3 VertexPosition;
in vec3 VertexColor;
uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec3 Color;

void main() {
    Color = vec3(1, 1, 1);
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Please someone tell me what is wrong with this? I have been working on this for almost a month now and I can move on unless this is done.

Also I have another shader that does color on the objects.

Comment: Why are you multiplying `vec4(1, 1, 1, 1)` by the model-view-projection in the shader? The idea is to transform the mesh's vertices by that matrix, so you should replace it with `vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0)`.

Comment: I was doing that, It did not work so I tried this

Comment: Get back the code that was using VertexPosition stream, and show some code around actual drawing - setting active shader program, loading uniforms, etc. For debugging purposes print the uniform location value. If it's -1 then you did something wrong while locating the uniform.

Comment: Yes, what @Vlad says. The code you have posted will definitely never do what you want, because always using a position of {1,1,1,1} is just a single point.